# Python WAND output incomplete

Tags: python, wand

I have an issue with Wand and PDF to JPG conversion. For somes files, I'll have very large output. Also, the conversion doesn't convert all the PDF pages. I didn't have any errors.

Here is my piece of code :

```
with Img(filename='/home/nathan/desktop/2021-06-04_FACTURES_anno.pdf', resolution=300) as pic:
    library.MagickResetIterator(pic.wand)
    pic.scene = 1  # Start cpt of filename at 1 instead of 0
    pic.compression_quality = 100
    pic.background_color = Color("white")
    pic.alpha_channel = 'remove'
    pic.save(filename='/home/nathan/desktop/test-%03d.jpg')
```

And if you need exemple, here is a PDF causing issue. I just have a 10MB JPG unique file on output instead of 3 files : [Download PDF](https://open-capture.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/2021-06-04_FACTURES_anno.pdf)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Code provided works as expected. How are the `pdf_name` & `output` strings defined?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I forgot that, I update the output asap

Comment: Do you have 3 jpg files as an output ?